# icCube definition of the icc-schema.xml

Tags: iccube

In the `icc-schema.xml jdbcDatatable column` there is a `tableType` and a `type` attribute.

Example:

> column name="first_opened_date" tableType="TIMESTAMP" type="DATETIME" selected="true" primaryKey="false"
>
> column name="prepared_food" tableType="BIT" type="BOOLEAN" selected="true" primaryKey="false"

I guessed the `tableType` refers to the data type as defined in the database and the `type` is an icCube internal identifier roughly related to `java.sql.Types`.

If this is right, the former [tableType] can be read from the `java.sql.Metadata.getColumns.getString("TYPE_NAME")` and the later [type] must be inferred from the `java.sql.Metadata.getColumns.getString("DATA_TYPE")`.

Is my guessing correct? Do you have a correspondence table? What is the impact of a wrong or missing attributes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming we are talking about JDBC tables.

"**tableType**" is not used as such within the code; it is displayed as an indication. 
The name is derived from the **java.sql.Types** integer as returned by the meta-information.

"**type**" is the actual data type of the column. Values read from the DB are converted
to this data type and then used to build dimensions and facts. This is the type displayed
in the table UI as "Output Type". Possible values are:

```
DATE     
DATETIME
BOOLEAN
DOUBLE
FLOAT
SHORT
INTEGER
LONG
STRING
UPPERCASE_STRING
JAVA_OBJECT
DB_TYPE_UNSUPPORTED
```

The mapping from java.sql.Types is as following:

```
DATE                from: Types.DATE
DATETIME            from: Types.TIMESTAMP
BOOLEAN             from: Types.BIT, Types.BOOLEAN
DOUBLE              from: Types.FLOAT, Types.DOUBLE, Types.NUMERIC, Types.DECIMAL
FLOAT               from: Types.REAL
SHORT               from: Types.TINYINT, Types.SMALLINT
INTEGER             from: Types.INTEGER
LONG                from: Types.BIGINT, Types.ROWID
STRING              from: Types.VARCHAR, Types.LONGVARCHAR, Types.NVARCHAR, Types.LONGNVARCHAR, Types.CHAR, Types.NCHAR
UPPERCASE_STRING    from: n/a
JAVA_OBJECT         from: Types.JAVA_OBJECT
DB_TYPE_UNSUPPORTED from: n/a
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

In complement to @Polizzi 's answer, and just in case you need it the other way round:

> ```
>     tableType = JDBCType.valueOf(dbtype).getName();
>     switch(dbtype){
>         case Types.DATE:
>             type = "DATE";
>             break;
>         case Types.TIMESTAMP:
>             type = "DATETIME";
>             break;            
>         case Types.BIT:
>             type = "BOOLEAN";
>             break;             
>         case Types.BOOLEAN:
>             type = "BOOLEAN";
>             break;             
>         case Types.FLOAT:
>             type = "DOUBLE";
>             break;          
>         case Types.DOUBLE:
>             type = "DOUBLE";
>             break;          
>         case Types.NUMERIC:
>             type = "DOUBLE";
>             break;              
>         case Types.DECIMAL:
>             type = "DOUBLE";
>             break;          
>         case Types.REAL:
>             type = "FLOAT";
>             break;           
>         case Types.TINYINT:
>             type = "SHORT";
>             break;           
>         case Types.SMALLINT:
>             type = "SHORT";
>             break;           
>         case Types.INTEGER:
>             type = "INTEGER";
>             break;         
>         case Types.BIGINT:
>             type = "LONG";
>             break;           
>         case Types.ROWID:
>             type = "LONG";
>             break;            
>         case Types.VARCHAR:
>             type = "STRING";
>             tableType = "VARCHAR("+length+")";
>             break;          
>         case Types.LONGVARCHAR:
>             type = "STRING";
>             tableType = "LONGVARCHAR("+length+")";
>             break;         
>         case Types.NVARCHAR:
>             type = "STRING";
>             tableType = "NVARCHAR("+length+")";
>             break;              
>         case Types.LONGNVARCHAR:
>             type = "STRING";
>             tableType = "LONGVARCHAR("+length+")";
>             break;          
>         case Types.CHAR:
>             type = "STRING";
>             tableType = "CHAR("+length+")";
>             break;              
>         case Types.NCHAR:
>             type = "STRING";
>             tableType = "NCHAR("+length+")";
>             break;               
>         case Types.JAVA_OBJECT:
>             type = "JAVA_OBJECT";
>             break; 
>         default:
>             type = "DB_TYPE_UNSUPPORTED";
>     }
> ```